# Cefsharp OffScreen set RequestContext

Tags: chromium-embedded, cefsharp, requestcontext, cefsharp.offscreen

I want to define a new RequestContext when using CefSharp OffScreen to prevent multiple browser instances sharing the same information (e.g. cookies).

I can simply do that with CefSharp WinForms like that:

```cs
RequestContextSettings requestContextSettings = new RequestContextSettings();

requestContextSettings.PersistSessionCookies = false;
requestContextSettings.PersistUserPreferences = false;

WebBrowser.RequestContext = new RequestContext(requestContextSettings);
```

But the RequestContext is readonly in the offscreen variant.
See http://cefsharp.github.io/api/57.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_OffScreen_ChromiumWebBrowser_RequestContext.htm
Why is that so? And are there other ways to accomplish it?

Comment: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/57.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_OffScreen_ChromiumWebBrowser__ctor.htm

Comment: Damn, I didn't look in the constructor parameters. Thank you!